# JS - Google charts - Cannot read property 'getChartLayoutInterface' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I've recently encountered an issue in which I'm given the console error of:

```
Cannot read property 'getChartLayoutInterface' of undefined
```

I've read up on other questions and from what I've seen it's because the Google Vizulation API has not loaded, my code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "assets/main/getFrontData.php",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              type: 'post',
              }).responseText;
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          var options = {
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            lineWidth: 4,
            areaOpacity: .2,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            colors: ['#007cb0'],
            width: 550,
            height: 300
          }    
          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.


         var boundingBox = chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getChartAreaBoundingBox(); 
   $('#backgroundChart').css('background-position', boundingBox.left + "px " + boundingBox.top + "px").css('background-size', boundingBox.width + "px " + boundingBox.height + "px");

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
</script>
```

The whole point being to put a background image in the graph the same size, any help would be appreciated on why the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem exists due to the fact that 'chart' is undefined prior to being referenced in this line

```
 var boundingBox = chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getChartAreaBoundingBox();
```

If you do not have an instance of the object defined before referencing that object, your environment will always return 'undefined'.

Perhaps relocating the instance of 'chart' will do you well. Move this section above the bounding box instantiation:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);`
```

This will ensure that the chart exists in your DOM, before referencing it for DOM manipulation.